# PHP class initialization

Tags: php

I'm quite new to PHP (coming from a rich C++ background). It's a good language, but I'm missing some of my C++ creature comforts, like structs. So I decided to make something that would act as a struct. I came up with the following:

```
class Struct
{
  public string $Foo;
  public string $Bar;
}
```

This looks great in my opinion. Now I would like to be able to initialize these struct variables in place like how you would be able to do in C++:

```
Struct Structure{ "One", "Two" }
```

Yet, to my understanding, the only way to do this in PHP is by creating a custom constructor. One downside to this though is that you'd need to create a custom constructor for every struct you make.
I think that you may be able to overcome this issue by using inheritance. But the question is: how? I was thinking of creating a constructor in the base class that can somehow initialize the variables of the derived class, but I'm not entirely sure how I would go about doing that (not to mention if that would be a 'good' solution).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can create a `stdclass` instance with properties using something like `$struct = (object) ['Foo' => 'One', 'Bar' => 'Two'];`

Comment: The all-mighty PHP data structure is the [array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). A PHP array is a combination of array, double-linked list and hash/map/dictionary (however you want to name it). This last one capability is usually used to simulate a `struct` (but the language does not provide any help to prevent using incorrect names for the "fields").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should maybe wait for PHP 8.0 (it's now in beta phase). There is a new feature called Constructor Promotion <sup>[RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/constructor_promotion)</sup> (which is accepted and implemented in PHP 8.0). You create a constructor along with its parameters, and at the same time, you define class properties:

```php
class Struct
{
  public function __construct(
    public string $Foo,
    public string $Bar,
  ) {
  }
}
```

Cool for a C++ developer! Now, you can instantiate it easily:

```php
$structure = new Struct("One", "Two");
```

Works perfectly (tested with PHP 8.0-beta2)!

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this. It may help you.

```
class Struct{
  public $foo;
  public $bar;
}

$obj = new MyStruct();
$obj->foo = 'One';
$obj->bar = 'Two';
```

Comment: I have considered doing this, however I wasn't happy with it seeing that I wouldn't be able to initialize it in one line like the aforementioned C++ style brace initialization

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a one-liner. An object without a class and a quick way to instantiate it.

The canonical way to do this in PHP is probably not an object, it's an array:

```
$foo = [
  'Foo' => 'One',
  'Bar' => 'Two'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I will add yet another solution which may or may not satisfy your needs. You can consider one of these solutions:

```
class Struct
{
  public string $Foo;
  public string $Bar;

  public static function fromAssoc(array $assoc): self
  {
      $instance = new self();
      $instance->Foo = $assoc['Foo'];
      $instance->Bar = $assoc['Bar'];
      return $instance;
  }

  public static function fromArray(array $array): self
  {
      $instance = new self();
      $instance->Foo = $assoc[0];
      $instance->Bar = $assoc[1];
      return $instance;
  }
}

$struct = Struct::fromAssoc([
  'Foo' => 'One',
  'Bar' => 'Two',
]);

$struct = Struct::fromArray(['One', 'Two']);
```

Pick your favourite

Comment: This would be a good solution if it weren't for the fact that to my knowledge you wouldn't be able to divide it into a parent class and derived classes. Reason I want to do this is to avoid having to copy the same logic to each and every struct I make.